# How to create a mirror environment of lambda AWS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have had a bunch of issues with few lambda functions in AWS. I would like to simulate the lambda environment in order to troubleshoot better what's wrong with my scripts. Unfortunately, the gotten errors in the logs are not too much useful. I have posted few of them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107439/python-3-6-lambda-function-error-errormessage-task-timed-out-after-59-06).

I would like to know then, how could I simulate in a docker image or even in an AMI the exact environment as my lambda function is running to catch more details on my error. What would you suggest me?

thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to run and debug Lambda functions locally. I'm not sure any of them are 100% representative of the actual Lambda environment, however.

[SAM Local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/test-sam-local.html) is one option provided by AWS, and is built on top of [Serverless Application Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/serverless_app.html) (SAM). Other options include [Cloud9](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/03/aws-cloud9-supports-local-debugging-of-aws-lambda-functions-in-python/), [emulambda](https://serverlesscode.com/post/emulambda-testing-aws-lambda/).

If your issues are timeouts then you should be able to detect where the delays are simply by adding more logging and review the resulting CloudWatch Logs. If the cause is high network latency for a given API request or SQL query then investigate the other end to determine why it responds slowly.

Comment: Examples about how to deploy the docker image here https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [python-lambda-local](https://pypi.org/project/python-lambda-local/) package or use [SAM Local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/test-sam-local.html) (it's still in Beta).